# Would it be okay to use 'who' in this sentence twice?

Tags: grammaticality

"By a commander called an induna who reported directly to Chaka" or " By a commander who is known as an induna who reported directly to Chaka."?
By a commander who was called an induna who reported directly to Chaka.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. Just drop the "who is," since the tense is wrong anyway.

> [...]by a commander known as an induna who reported directly to Chaka.